# Why .isin() does not work but str.contains() does work for an object column in my pd.DataFrame()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, isin

The `str.contains()` method filters the dataframe to only contain values with `"A"`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"City": ["A","B","C","D","A","A"]})
df[df["City"].str.contains("A")]
```

But if I try to use `.isin()` on the same dataframe the output results in an empty series:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"City": ["A","B","C","D","A","A"]})
df[df["City"].isin("A")]
```

Comment: You are missing the `square-brackets[]`. Do this: `df[df["City"].isin(["A"])]`.

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) takes a `list` (more specifically, a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) or list-like) of things to search for.

Use `.isin(["A"])` instead of `.isin("A")`:

```py
df[df["City"].isin(["A"])]
#                  ^   ^
```

Output:

```py
>>> df[df["City"].isin(["A"])]
  City
0    A
4    A
5    A
```

Because of this trait of `isin`, you can search for multiple items at once:

```py
>>> df[df["City"].isin(["A", "B"])]
  City
0    A
1    B
4    A
5    A
```